# Calculate total number of unique rows and save the value in a new column

Tags: python, data-manipulation

[image: Sample Data]

How do I get from that to this:

[image]

I know I can count using len() by putting condition inside but actual data is really big, it has around 14k rows. So it is not realistic to find each unique rows and then count the total number of each unique rows. Is there any easier solution ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `groupby` on all columns and `count` (pick one column):

```
df.groupby(df.columns)['Date'].count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby, size and reset_index:

```
df.groupby(list(df.columns)).size().reset_index(name = "total")
```